# ssh possible dns spoofing when logging into multiple machines via single host

Tags: ssh, dns, rsa, spoofing

I log in to the rhel5 machines at my school from home via ssh and it automatically sends me to the computer with the least load. So `ssh -Y itsme@myShcool.edu` will send me to either mySchoolA.edu mySchoolB.edu, or mySchoolC.edu. I can log into the individual computers with no issue but when, but when I use `itsme@myShcool.edu` , sometimes I get a message about a man-in-the-middle attack and possible DNS spoofing, and I'm directed to ~/.ssh/known_hosts to remove the offending key. Removing the offending key works the first time I log in (I'm prompted to add the host to known_hosts, which I confirm).

Is it possible to log in using `itsme@myShcool.edu` and not get this message nor have to manually remove the offending keys each time?

One thing I tried that doesn't seem to work is adding the following to ~/.ssh/config

```
Host hostIPaddress
StrictHostKeyChecking no 
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the machines are all being accessed via the same hostname, they should have the same key.  I would recommend talking to the system administrator and have him synchronize the keys across machines.

Comment: @heavyd I'll see if I can talk to the sys admin about synchronizing the host key. Thanks for the help advice.

Comment: @ssnobody I don't think that the post you linked is the same issue. They were  having trouble editing known_hosts while keeping hashes. I'm having an issue with different machines accessed via the same hostname and apparently not having the same key. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Looks like the same issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

No.  That is a security feature of SSH to know you've connected to the right machine and your connection is not being intercepted.  You certainly don't want to short-circuit that, it would allow a real man-in-the-middle attack and you'd never know it.

If this is how your school's IT administrator *meant* for this to work -- round-robin a cluster of machines with the same DNS name -- he/she would have copied the SSH private identity key to all the machines in the cluster so this authentication problem doesn't occur.